# how to calculate Content-Length in http protocol？my result is 296，but correct result is 298?

Tags: http, content-length

[image: raw data]

why  did I lose two？thanks。 i calcute by (1b0-90)*16+8 = 0x120 * 16 +8=288+8=296

Answer (score 0):

because ODOA，in  http protocol  there are two odoa, but in　this package,there are three,so the last odoa is content.